# Размер текста заголовка экрана app_name

Tags: android

Имеется две разметки layout-sw200dp и layout-sw600dp.
Как изменить шрифт текста заголовка экрана в зависимости от ширины экрана.
В layout-sw200dp текст не вмещается в экран, появляются точки вместо букв.
Можно уменьшить количество слов в названии,но хотелось бы разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте разные размеры шрифтов sp для разных экранов. Создайте в values > dimens еще две для sw200 и sw600 помимо основного

Comment: Не в `values-dimens` а просто `values`

Comment: Ой, извините, не заметил

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам на заметку

```
values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

Насчёт разных размеров на разных экранах

1) Создайте папки с именами в таблице выше (слева) и в каждой создайте по файлу `dimen.xml`. Запишите в них разный размер, выраженный в `sp`, так как текст лучше всего представлять в нем. Примерно так

```
<resources>
<dimen name="toolbar_title">20sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

В каждой папке. Меняется только размер `20sp`.

2) Заставить `Toolbar` использовать стиль для тайтла

```
app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
```

3) И стиль в `styles.xml`

```
<style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/toolbar_title</item>
</style>
```

У вас должна остаться папка `values`, все остаётся также, не запутайтесь